# How to extend base class to child class in python and printing child class value?

Tags: python-3.x

when i try to extend base class to child class it doesn't work properly

it shows error
**b1 = B("adnan", 25, "male")
TypeError: object() takes no parameters**

here is my **code** :

```
class A:

    def letter(self,name,age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age

class B(A):
    def farhan(self,gender):
        self.gender=gender
b1=B("adnan",25,"male")
print(b1.name,b1.age,b1.gender)
```

Comment: "it doesn't work properly" is not a problem description. Please describe _how exactly_ your code "doesn't work" and include any errors you're getting.

Comment: b1 = B("adnan", 25, "male")
TypeError: object() takes no parameters this is the error

Answer (score 1):

None of your classes have an `__init__` method, which is used to initialise the class. When you do: `B("adnan",25,"male")`, it's translated to a call to `B.__init__`:

```
B.__init__(<object of type B>, "adnan", 25, "male")
```

The default implementation of `__init__` supplied by the class `object` takes no parameters, which is exactly what the error is saying. `A` inherits from `object` (`issubclass(B, object) == True`), so its default `__init__` method is the same as that of `object`.

You can try this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        super().__init__(name, age)  # initialise parent
        self.gender = gender
```

Comment: In Java I can  extend Parent class to child class and use all things from parent class . I have name and age to class A (parent class) .. Why i have to initialize it again to child class ? i want to add just gender here in class B .. do you understand my point ?

Comment: You can use everything you inherited from class `A` in the child class too. `super().__init__(...)` runs `A`'s `__init__` method _on the `B` object_, so that `<B object>.name` and `<B object>.age` are created and initialised.

Answer (score 0):

When you write something like

```
b1 = B("adnan", 25, "male")
```

You are creating a new instance of the class 'B'. When you do that, you're calling the `__init__` method of that class. A possible solution would be in the lines of:

```
class B(A):
def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.gender = gender
```

You need to brush up your Python OOP skills! A nice source is https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/

Comment: In Java I can  extend Parent class to child class and use all things from parent class . I have name and age to class A (parent class) .. Why i have to initialize it again to child class ? i want to add just gender here in class B and i want to print all the value .. do you understand my point ?